# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type Function

Tags: flutter

I want to feed Two to the function. When function receives Two as the data, it should print success to the console. But it throws an error.

**Error:** `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type Function`

***~~~PAGE1 for button***

```
const ToolSetButton(
      {Key? key,
            this.function = myRunFunction,

const Function myRunFunction = defaultFunction;

void defaultFunction() {
  print('Button Tapped');
}
```

***PAGE 2 where the above widget being used***

**List**

```
enum ButtonList {One, Two, Three}
```

**Calling function**

```
function: testFunc(ButtonList.Two)),
```

**Function**

```
testFunc( ButtonList type) {

if (type == ButtonList.Two ){print('sucess ')};
    }
```

***~~~PAGE 3 which is executing the function***

**Executing function inside an inkwell**

```
class ToolSetButton extends StatefulWidget {
  
  final Function function ;
}

child: InkWell(
                      splashColor: Colors.white,
                      onTap: () {
                        Function.apply(widget.function, [], {});
                      },
```

Comment: How do you call the function ?

Comment: @esentis inside a inkwell on tap. `onTap: () {
                        Function.apply(widget.function, [], {});
                      },`

Comment: Share also where you call the `ToolSetButton`

Comment: it's called by a different page. `ToolSetButton` is the top class for that page.

Comment: Wait I'll separate the pages above.

Comment: Copy the code where you call it, I would like to see how you pass the `function` variable.

Comment: @esentis edited the above code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238672/discussion-between-pretty-girl-and-esentis).

Comment: That error indicates, You are assigning Null to the Function type somewhere.

Comment: It would be nice if you post your full code

Comment: @Balaji it's huge contains alot of code and I tried to extract the problematic code from the pages

Comment: I got the solution below. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it correctly you want when you tap on the `ToolSetButton` if it's of type `ButtonList.two` you want success to be printed on console. A simple approach would be to change your `ToolSetButton` widget to have a `buttonType` parameter (**EDIT: you can also pass your own function**):

```dart
enum ButtonList { One, Two, Three }

class ToolSetButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const ToolSetButton({
    required this.buttonType,
    required this.buttonText,
    required this.myFunction,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final ButtonList buttonType;
  final String buttonText;
  final Function myFunction;
  @override
  _ToolSetButtonState createState() => _ToolSetButtonState();
}

class _ToolSetButtonState extends State<ToolSetButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        widget.myFunction();
      },
      child: Text(widget.buttonText),
    );
  }
}
```

Now when you use the create `ToolSetButton` you could define its type for later use, and also pass your own function to be executed when `onTap`:

```dart
class TestClass extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestClass({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  void testFunc(ButtonList type) {
    if (type == ButtonList.Two) {
      print('sucess ');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          ToolSetButton(
            buttonText: 'One',
            buttonType: ButtonList.One,
            myFunction: () {
              testFunc(ButtonList.One);
            },
          ),
          ToolSetButton(
            buttonText: 'Two',
            buttonType: ButtonList.Two,
            myFunction: () {
              testFunc(ButtonList.Two);
            },
          ),
          ToolSetButton(
            buttonText: 'Three',
            buttonType: ButtonList.Three,
            myFunction: () {
              testFunc(ButtonList.Three);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You're having the function inside the inkwell above. But what I want to do is to pass the entire function from other page to the inkwell. In my code above that's what I'm doing `function: testFunc(ButtonList.Two)),` that is sending.  Here inkwell is receiving `Function.apply(widget.function, [], {});`. It worked fine until I introduce a list. I think some where I need to define something as a list or array or something. But I don't know where. Debugging also does not provide that useful info.

Comment: Editted the answer to include your own function.